# Photos stopped showing up in HTML code?

Tags: html, image, nav

I am trying to upload pictures to my online portfolio, and all was working well (pictures were showing up and everything), however, when I revisited my site the pictures show up blank. This is my code:

```
       </nav>
          <div class="centerthis">
          <img src="../img/clock.jpg" alt="clock">
          <img src="../img/thisismyspace.jpg" alt="nikeontrain">
          <img src="../img/honest.jpg" alt="honest">
          <img src="../img/therailway.jpg"  alt="train">
          <img src="../dezzycuute.jpg" alt="dezzy">

           </div>
          </body>

          </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and i discovered that my transfer type on the FTP package i was using was switched to ASCII after a new version was installed and from reading up on this, ASCII is fine for your .html / text files, ASCII will corrupt images etc.  So perhaps you should check your FTP software and set file transfer type to Binary for images.

Also perhaps test it with a full root address to the images -

```
    "http://www.yourdomain.com/images/image.jpg".
```

If neither of these help you out, perhaps check your server responses for the images and post them here to allow others to better understand your problem as you may just have your address wrong or caching is causing a problem etc...

Hope this helps as I spent quite a while figuring this out too.